Mount File System within docker (for paperless-ngx)
I want to mount the path /data/nextcloud_data/Dokumente into my docker.
docker container ls




CONTAINER ID
IMAGE
COMMAND
CREATED
STATUS
PORTS
NAMES




78690b704594
ghcr.io/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx:latest
"/sbin/docker-entryp…"
6 months ago
Up 4 days (healthy)
0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp
paperless-ngx-webserver-1


184a2d6a0a29
gotenberg/gotenberg:7.10
"/usr/bin/tini -- go…"
7 months ago
Up 4 days
3000/tcp
paperless-ngx-gotenberg-1


838d4477712a
redis:7
"docker-entrypoint.s…"
7 months ago
Up 4 days
6379/tcp
paperless-ngx-broker-1


f80fdd652715
ghcr.io/paperless-ngx/tika:latest
"/bin/sh -c 'exec ja…"
7 months ago
Up 4 days
9998/tcp
paperless-ngx-tika-1



So I try:
sudo docker run -t -i -v /data/nextcloud_data/Dokumente:/data/nextcloud_data/Dokumente ghcr.io/paperless-ngx/paperless-ngx /bin/bash

But it keeps failing

Paperless-ngx docker container starting...
Creating directory /usr/src/paperless/data/index
Creating directory /usr/src/paperless/media/documents
Creating directory /usr/src/paperless/media/documents/originals
Creating directory/usr/src/paperless/media/documents/thumbnails
Creating directoryscratch directory /tmp/paperless
Adjusting permissions of paperless files. This may take a while.
Waiting for Redis...
Redis ping #0 failed.
Error: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379.
Connection refused..
Waiting 5s
Redis ping #1 failed.
Error: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Waiting 5s
Redis ping #2 failed.
Error: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Waiting 5s
Redis ping #3 failed.
Error: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused..
Waiting 5s

What am I doing wrong?

I did not solve it, only found some clue within /var/lib/docker/containers there are mount points defined, but I cant edit these files / they are reset to default every time I start a container...

Although i am not familiar with paperless-ngx this error looks like you incorrectly configured your applications running in your containers:
Redis ping #0 failed. Error: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379

The ping happens inside the paperless container, as such localhost referes to the container, not your host. I suggest you to use docker networks. This will allow you to use the container names as the host names in the respective configurations of the applications.

Thanks. I tried this, but it didnt solve my problem:
docker network create -d bridge paperless-redis
docker network connect paperless-redis paperless-ngx-webserver-1;
docker network connect paperless-redis paperless-ngx-broker-1;```

The Problem seems to be on a different part. As when starting the docker the log sais:
`[celery.worker.consumer.connection] Connected to redis://broker:6379//

The Problem seems to be on a different part. As when starting the docker the log sais:
[celery.worker.consumer.connection] Connected to redis://broker:6379// (connection between the dockers seem to work). Even if I cant find them using
docker network ls

Do you still get the same error message with the failed redis pings? I'd assume that the message would have changed, if paperless-ngx-webserver-1 could connect to paperless-ngx-broker-1.

I didn't realy solve it the way I wanted. But I reinstalled the docker container so now I can use my mount points.
However, if anyone knows the answere, feel free to post it - for other people or for future use.
